# How to boot EFI and MBR

Tags: boot, grub, slackware

I have two hard drives, in one I have windows 10 (sda) and in the other slackware linux (sdb).
I had ELILO but this one did not recognize the windows menu entry, so I deleted ELILO and  installed GRUB, 
but it can't recognize the windows partition either.

```
Slackware linux (sdb) 
- GPT
- sdb1 EFI Partition
- sdb2 ROOT Partition
- sdb3 HOME Partition
- sdb4 SWAP Partition

Windows 10 (sda)
- MBR
sda1 - System Partition
sda2 - NTFS partition
sda3 - NTFS Partition
```

In my system BIOS sdb boot first than sda

Slackware run very well on boot but I can't make that recognize windows OS

The last commands what I typed was

```
rm -rf /boot/efi/EFI/Slackware/*.*
grub-install /dev/sdb1
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and now ELILO gone, GRUB handle boot proccess, Slackware boot very well, but the windows partition still is not recognized by GRUB

I will apreciate any advice thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) Backup Windows and reinstal it in EFI mode with repartition sda in GPT.

OR

2) Reinstall Slackware in non-EFI mode.

EFI or non-EFI mode boot is selected by motherboard firmware, not by bootloader itself.